# how to extract a column of CSV file in scala spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

suppose these are my CSV file:

```
21628000000;21650466094
21697098269;21653506459
21653000000;21624124815
21624124815;21650466094
21650466094;21650466094
21624124815;21697098269
21697098269;21628206459
21628000000;21624124815
21650466094;21628206459
21628000000;21628206459
```

I want to count the number of occurrences in the first column to have a result:

```
(21628000000,4)
(21697098269,2)
(21624124815,2)
(21650466094,2)
```

i've tried:

```
object CountOcc {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("Word Count")
    .setMaster("local")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    //loading text file into textFile object .(RDD)
    val textFile = sc.textFile(args(0))

   //read the line , split the line into words
    val words = textFile.flatMap (line => line.split(";"))
    val cols = words.map(_.trim)
    println(s"${cols(0)}") //error
    cols.foreach(println)
   sc.stop()

  }
}
```

I get an error  **org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD error [String] Does not take parameters**

So I can't make cols(0) or cols(1),how I can have only the first column so I can calculate the occurrence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
val words = textFile.map (line => line.split(";")(0)).map(p=>(p,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect()
```

Comment: I changed. flatMap => map and the line split to 0

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

I try

```
val words = textFile.flatMap (line => line.split(";")(1))
```

I get :

```
2
1
6
5
0
4
6
6
0
9
4
2
1
6
5
3
5
0
6
4
5
9
2
1
6.....
```

Comment: yes. stupid of me - it should be map and not flatMap. I edited accordingly

Comment: why i get this output, but when i do map it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

This scala job will work correctly print the first column of the CSV file.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object CountOcc {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Read CSV")
      .getOrCreate()

    val csvDF = spark.read.csv(args(0))

    val firstColumnList = csvDF.map( x => x.getString(0))

    firstColumnList.foreach(println(_))

    spark.close
  }
}
```

Hope it helps